# Why are both filenames in directory printed while only content of one file is extended in the list?

Tags: python, list, extend, with-statement, listdir

I'm new with Python and I'm sure the mistake is obvious for most of you. I try to iterate through a folder using `os.listdir()`. Only filenames with `.out` are important. I want to extend the list `out = []` by every entry of every `*.out` file. To check whether my if loop works, I print the filenames (two filenames are printed) but only the content of one file is extended in the list `out = []`.

```py
out = []

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.out'):
        print(filename)
        with open(filename) as f:
            out.extend(f)
```

Comment: why are you opening the file in the second to last line?  Seems like if you removed that and tabbled the extend line back to align with the print statement you will get what you need.

Comment: There's too little to work with here. The code looks fine. What's actually in `path`, what are the contents of those files, and what's the final value of `out` after the loop?

Comment: Are you on Python 3.4+? If so, please consider migrating your code to [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). I can show you how if you need it.

Comment: @Chris, can you elaborate on that? If the `with` line is removed, won't `out.extend(f)` fail because `f` is no longer defined?

Comment: @Kevin yes I misunderstood the question, i thought you just wanted to extend the names of the files, not the content.

Comment: Oh, makes sense. I agree that you don't need an `open` call if you only want to collect a list of filenames.

Comment: If you just want a list of file names ending in `.out`, you can use `glob()` instead.

Comment: Do you need to do `with open(path + filename) as f`? Just an idea.

Comment: In path there are only 2 .out files + script.ipynb and a folder with .ipynb_checkpoints (i work with jupyter notebook). The file's content is just a list with a new line for every entry. The final value of out is ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']. That is completely fine for the first .out file. Although the second .out file's is printed, the content isn't extended in the out list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in one of my comments, if you are on Python 3.4+, [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) will make your life a lot easier.

To get a list of all file names ending in `.out` from folder `folder`, you simply do:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('folder')

outs = [_.name for _ in folder.glob('*.out')]
```

And that is it.

If you want to populate a list called `lines` with all `*.out` files contents you can simply need to:

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('folder')

lines = []

lines.extend([_.read_text().split() for _ in folder.glob('*.out')])
```

And here is a small proof of concept:

```sh
$ tree temp
temp
├── file1.out
├── file2.out
├── file3.txt
└── file4.txt

0 directories, 4 files
$
```

```py
Python 3.7.5 (default, Dec 15 2019, 17:54:26) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> folder = Path('temp')
>>> outs = [_.name for _ in folder.glob('*.out')]
>>> txts = [_.name for _ in folder.glob('*.txt')]
>>> outs
['file1.out', 'file2.out']
>>> txts
['file3.txt', 'file4.txt']
>>>
```

Here is another way for concatenation of the contents:

```sh
$ cat temp/file1.out 
1
2
3
4
$ cat temp/file2.out 
5
6
7
8
$
```

```py
>>> lines = [l for _ in folder.glob('*.out') for l in _.read_text().split()]
>>> lines
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
>>>
```

I hope it helps.